# Does it make sense to say that microtubules are arranged in a ring around the cell periphery?

Tags: cell-biology, fluorescent-microscopy, cytoskeleton

I am reading a journal [paper](https://journals.biologists.com/jcs/article/109/6/1537/25005/Cellular-phosphorylation-of-tau-by-GSK-3-beta) and it is about how the organisation of microtubules are altered in CHO cells that overexpress microtubule-associated protein Tau.
In the paper, the authors found that overexpressing Tau in CHO cells resulted in changes in the organisation of microtubules. In the paper they state:

> Non-transfected, interphase cells contained typical radiating arrays
> of microtubules that often could be seen to emanate from a microtubule
> organising centre when labelled with the tubulin antibody. However,
> transfection of tau into these cells dramatically altered this pattern
> of labelling. In cells expressing high levels of tau (as judged by
> intensity of fluorescence staining), bundles of microtubules could be
> discerned which often formed a ring, or spiral around the
> circumference of the cell (Fig. 1A,B).

I have described what the authors have discovered in the tau-transfected cells in my own words: "In cells overexpressing Tau, microtubules were bundled and arranged in a ring structure around the cell periphery".

I have read [online](http://www.informatics.jax.org/vocab/gene_ontology/GO:0071944) that the cell periphery is the part of the cell encompassing the cell cortex, the plasma membrane and any external encapsulating structures.

By saying that the microtubules were arranged in a ring around the cell periphery, I want to convey that the they are arranged in a ring around the perimeter of the cell. However, I was wondering if using the phrasing "*around* the cell periphery" makes sense, because I do not want people to misunderstand my sentence and think that I am saying that the microtubules are arranged in a ring *outside* the plasma membrane by using the word *around*.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: I read periphery as meaning *outside and proximal*.  So I would interpret *around the cell periphery* as referring to something that is closely associated with but external to a cell.

Comment: Are you asking because you are trying to avoid plagiarism? Otherwise why not use the original phrasing?